# Is there a CiviCRM extension or functionality similar to what Doodle or when2meet provide?

Tags: civievent, activities

I've used Doodle.com and when2meet.com for scheduling meetings, and wondering if there is an extension that works similarly, or built-in functionality, for CiviCRM.

Both sites allow a user to create multiple meeting choices with different dates and times, share a link, let others choose from among those time slots, and then choose a final meeting date and time based on user responses.

Thanks!

Comment: Which CMS are you using?

Comment: @ChristianWach I'm using CiviCRM 5.25 and Drupal 7.70 .

Comment: Ah, okay - had it been WordPress I'd have had an answer for you. Good luck!

Comment: @ChristianWach Ok thanks so please post that answer for the folks using Civi with WordPress :)

Comment: I use https://github.com/christianwach/rendez-vous and then integrate with CiviEvents.

Comment: @ChristianWach thanks for the link! This is a good answer, would you like to add it as such? Also, is there a site running Rendez-Vous that you can point to as an example of it in use - a demo site or otherwise?